# presentModalViewController from app delegate

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad

How can I present a modal view controller from the app delegate's view, the top most? Trying to present a modal view controller from a UIView, which made me confused.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Application delegates do not manage a view. You should present a modal view controller from the `-viewDidAppear:` method of the first view controller that gets put on screen in `-application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:`.

Comment: I am actually trying to present a modalViewController from a UIView, and trying to present this on the top most viewcontroller, any idea?

Comment: Modal view controllers can only be presented by other view controllers. The views that they manage have no knowledge of their own controller let alone other view controllers.

Comment: While this answer points out some of the OP's misunderstandings, it doesn't really answer the question. Please see my answer re: UIWindow

Comment: Creating a new window is, to the user, functionally equivalent to presenting a controller from the `rootViewController` as pointed out by @XJones. OP seems like he's just getting started in iOS development and I'm trying to steer him towards best practices given the information provided in the question. App delegate bloat is so last year.

Comment: Not if the `rootViewController` is already presenting a modal view controller. While I agree the code shouldn't be in the app delegate - showing him how to put code there (which he can later refactor elsewhere) is perfectly acceptable.

Comment: True, that would cause an issue. My point is that there are better places for this logic than to just dump it all in the app delegate.

Comment: Agreed on that point - but it doesn't change the fact that Apple has a specific approach for this kind of thing - and that's to use a `UIWindow` with the `windowLevel` set to `UIWindowLevelAlert`. Your comment about where the code goes is irrelevant to the answer.

Comment: Be sure to called super with the viewDidAppear: method if you override.

Answer (score 12):

Use your `rootViewController`. You can present a modal view controller from any view controller subclass. If your root VC is a UITabBarController, then you can do:

```
[self.tabBarController presentModalViewControllerAnimated:YES]
```

or if its a navigation controller:

```
[self.navigationController presentModalViewControllerAnimated:YES]
```

etc.

**EDIT: MVC**

By trying to present a controller from within a view you are breaking the MVC pattern. Generally, a view is concerned with its appearance and exposing interfaces to communicate user interface state to its controller. For example, if you have a `UIButton` in your view and you want it to present a modal view controller, you don't hard wire the view to do this. Instead, when a controller instantiates the view, the controller configures the button by setting itself as a target to receive the `touchUpInside` action where it can present the appropriate modal view controller.

The view itself does not (and should not) have this contextual knowledge to do the work of a controller.

Comment: Doesn't work if the `rootViewController` is already presenting a modal view controller.

Comment: true, this was just an example. I don't know the full logic of the OP's app. Also agree with all that understanding proper techniques is better so you can deviate with full knowledge of what you're doing when necessary.

Comment: A `UIWindow`-based approach works always, across the board, with no custom logic... just like a `UIAlertView` works always.

Comment: that's assuming OP wants that behavior. He may want the modal transition as well. You can do that with `UIWindow` if you write the code. Your answer is fine, what is best for the OP is hard to discern exactly. He has multiple options to solve the problem and I support both showing him the options and encouraging proper understanding/use of development paradigms.

Comment: I agree with XJones. Its a good answer, and it works. I use it a lot. But I didn't understand what is the problem whit: _"By trying to present a controller from within a view you are breaking the MVC pattern"_ Can someone explain it some other way? Thanks

Comment: MVC = Model/View/Controller. This is the design pattern used in iOS applications. The topic is too big to discuss in detail here. Quickly, it defines/enforces the separation between Model (data), Views (UI), and Controllers (app logic).

Answer (score 10):

The best way to do this is to create a new `UIWindow`, set it's `windowLevel` property, and present your `UIViewController` in that window.

This is how `UIAlertView`s work.

**Interface**

```
@interface MyAppDelegate : NSObject <UIApplicationDelegate>

@property (nonatomic, strong) UIWindow * alertWindow;

...

- (void)presentCustomAlert;

@end
```

**Implementation:**

```
@implementation MyAppDelegate

@synthesize alertWindow = _alertWindow;

...

- (void)presentCustomAlert
{
    if (self.alertWindow == nil)
    {
        CGRect screenBounds = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds];
        UIWindow * alertWindow = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:screenBounds];
        alertWindow.windowLevel = UIWindowLevelAlert;
    }

    SomeViewController * myAlert = [[SomeViewController alloc] init];
    alertWindow.rootViewController = myAlert;

    [alertWindow makeKeyAndVisible];
}

@end
```